# Windows Azure access App_Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I need to write file to App_Data folder in Asp.Net MVC project. It works locally, but when I deployed it to Windows Azure I received error like:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\codehint\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Data\text.txt'.
```

I need to use third party library that have to get read/write access to App_Data folder.

I use code like this:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/text.txt");
using (var file = new StreamWriter(path))
{
   file.Write("test line");
   file.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Is your application running as cloud service or websites?

Comment: website, here is the page  http://www.codehint.ru/test/appdata, but locally it works

Comment: oh.. Something was happened. it works

Answer (score 9):

If App_Data folder was empty, it was not deployed, so you need to create it

see my reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24671416/631527)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS2017 and right click on the App_Data folder there is an option to Publish folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by creating the initial file in my solution's `App_Data` folder, and then I added the file to the solution by right-clicking on App_Start and choosing Add->Existing Item...

[image]

It needed to be added to the solution in order to be published.